# How to register for an "uevent" from a user application in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

I have written battery driver and that driver sends an `uevent` when a power supply is changed, i.e. from AC to battery

When I run `udevadm monitor` I see an **KERNEL** and **UDEV** `CHANGE` events from `power_supply` subsystem upon removing AC supply.

My requirement is to notify the user application when there is an `CHANGE` event from `power_supply` subsystem. I do not want to poll for kernel message or netlink socket from user application.

> Is it possible for me to register/listen for this particular `uevent`
> from user application and gets something like callback function when
> an event occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible and there is a great reference [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev#Triggering_desktop_notifications_from_a_udev_rule). In the reference they use a change rule for a similar application:

```
# Rule for when switching to battery
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{type}=="Mains", ATTR{online}=="0", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/USERNAME/.Xauthority" RUN+="/usr/bin/su USERNAME_TO_RUN_SCRIPT_AS -c /usr/local/bin/brightness_notification.sh"
```

The `ACTION=="change"` registers a rule for a change event. The `SUBSYSTEM` and `ATTR` parameters specify the rule to only apply to a certain device or devices (you can get these for your device from udevadm). The `RUN` parameter is how you run a userspace executable when the event is seen. In the case below they also use the `ENV` parameter to pass a environment variable to the executable and they also use the `su` command in `RUN` to run the executable as another user, but this is probably not necessary for most applications.